# VBA code to auto hide rows based upon text in cell A1

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba

I cannot seem to get my code for this sheet to work properly.

I have code in there functioning fine which will hide rows based upon whether cells in a range are empty.

However I would like to additionally hide two rows based upon the value in cell A1.

At the moment I have the following:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim xRg As Range
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        For Each xRg In Range("A6:A9")
            If xRg.Value = "" Then
                xRg.EntireRow.Hidden = True
            Else
                xRg.EntireRow.Hidden = False
            End If
        Next xRg
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

I then would like to add some combination of the following:

```
If Range("A1") = "CODE 4 - ERROR" Then

    Rows("35").EntireRow.Hidden = False    
Else
    Rows("35").EntireRow.Hidden = True
End If
        If Range("A1") = "CODE 5 - INCONSISTENCY" Then
    Rows("35").EntireRow.Hidden = False
Else
    Rows("35").EntireRow.Hidden = True
End If
    If Range("A1") = "CODE 1 - PASS" Then
    Rows("35:36").EntireRow.Hidden = False
Else
    Rows("35:36").EntireRow.Hidden = True
End If
```

But I can't seem to get the latter to work either on its own or in conjunction with the above. Any suggestions?

Comment: As the answer suggests you need to rewrite your code to nest your if statements. The way it is currently written it will go through each test, while you probably want it to end after the first true test. Another option is to use the `SELECT CASE/END SELECT` formulation but probably for more than 3 cases.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome!

As far as I was able to read and understand your code, the normal state of rows 35:36 is "hidden". In case of CODE 4 OR CODE 5, row 35 should be displayed, and in case of CODE 1, both rows 35 and 36 should be displayed, right?

I would write it exactly like this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim xRg As Range
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        For Each xRg In Range("A6:A9")
            If xRg.Value = "" Then
                xRg.EntireRow.Hidden = True
            Else
                xRg.EntireRow.Hidden = False
            End If
        Next xRg
        Rows("35:36").EntireRow.Hidden = True
        If ((Range("A1") = "CODE 4 - ERROR") Or (Range("A1") = "CODE 5 - INCONSISTENCY")) Then
            Rows("35").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        ElseIf (Range("A1") = "CODE 1 - PASS") Then
            Rows("35:36").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        End If
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Worked perfectly, thank you so much.